# Unable to find the vsmdi-file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, cmd, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Where can I find the VSMDI file needed to execute the codedUI tests outside of visual studios, in a command prompt.

I googled and found the following line;

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86 ^&^& cd C:\Users\YOUR_USER_HERE\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\YOUR_PROJECT ^&^& Mstest /testmetadata:YOUR_PROJECT.vsmdi /testlist:YOUR_TEST_LIST ^& pause
```

However whenever I input my specifications I end up with the following error:

> File "YOUR_PROJECT.vsmdi" not found .

I'm pretty pressured time wise and really appreciate any suggestions you guys may have.

Comment: vsmdi files are deprecated in Visual Studio 2012, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh507838%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which has some notes on using them.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it lives near your solution file...

Especially the solution where you made the testproject( which I moved once to another solution and had this problem...)

[Explanation of vsmdi file](http://blog.mitchdenny.com/2011/02/10/what-is-a-vsmdi-file/)